# I´m creating Mesh in GMSH with python and my result is with invisible surfaces

Tags: python, gmsh

I´m trying to mesh a Volume with gmsh in Python and so far everything is fine, but my result in GMSH is with invisible surfaces. Because I want to build it later on as a structured grid it's quite annoying to click my way through

I can make the surfaces visible via

options -> mesh -> visibilty -> and then mark [2d element faces] and remove the mark on [3d element edges]

default is:

[2d element edges] and [3d element edges]

marked.

Is there a way for me to solve this in my code?

thank you all very much in advance and greetings

Michael

Here is my code:

import gmsh
import math

```
def main():
gmsh.initialize()

# alias to facilitate code writing
factory = gmsh.model.geo

# default mesh size
lc = 1.

# Geometry
# points
p1 = factory.addPoint(0., 0., 0., lc)
p2 = factory.addPoint(10., 0., 0., lc)
p3 = factory.addPoint(0., 10., 0., lc)
p4 = factory.addPoint(4., 0., 0., lc)
p5 = factory.addPoint(0., 4., 0., lc)
p6 = factory.addPoint(4., 4., 0., lc)
angle = math.pi/4.
p7 = factory.addPoint(10*math.cos(angle), 10*math.sin(angle),       0., lc)

# lines
l1 = factory.addLine(p5, p6)
l2 = factory.addLine(p6, p4)
l3 = factory.addLine(p4, p1)
l4 = factory.addLine(p1, p5)
l5 = factory.addLine(p4, p2)
l6 = factory.addLine(p5, p3)
l7 = factory.addLine(p6, p7)
l8 = factory.addCircleArc(p2, p1, p7)
l9 = factory.addCircleArc(p7, p1, p3)

# curve loops
cl1 = factory.addCurveLoop([l3, l4, l1, l2])
cl2 = factory.addCurveLoop([l7, l9, -l6, l1])
cl3 = factory.addCurveLoop([l5, l8, -l7, l2])

# surfaces
s1 = factory.addPlaneSurface([cl1])
s2 = factory.addPlaneSurface([cl2])
s3 = factory.addPlaneSurface([cl3])

# extrusions
dx = 5.
num_els_z = 10
factory.extrude([(2, s1), (2, s2), (2, s3)], 0., 0., dx,
                numElements=[num_els_z], recombine=True)

factory.synchronize()

# Meshing
meshFact = gmsh.model.mesh

# transfinite curves
n_nodes = 10
# "Progression" 1 is default
meshFact.setTransfiniteCurve(l1, numNodes=n_nodes)
meshFact.setTransfiniteCurve(l2, numNodes=n_nodes)
meshFact.setTransfiniteCurve(l3, numNodes=n_nodes)
meshFact.setTransfiniteCurve(l4, numNodes=n_nodes)
meshFact.setTransfiniteCurve(l5, numNodes=n_nodes)
meshFact.setTransfiniteCurve(l6, numNodes=n_nodes)
meshFact.setTransfiniteCurve(l7, numNodes=n_nodes)
meshFact.setTransfiniteCurve(l8, numNodes=n_nodes)
meshFact.setTransfiniteCurve(l9, numNodes=n_nodes)
# transfinite surfaces
meshFact.setTransfiniteSurface(s1)
meshFact.setTransfiniteSurface(s2)
meshFact.setTransfiniteSurface(s3)

# mesh
meshFact.generate(2)
meshFact.recombine()
meshFact.generate(3)

gmsh.fltk.run()

gmsh.finalize()


if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

[This is my gmsh model as it is without any work on the visibility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QblKV.png)
[This is how I would like to get it straight out of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gChKH.png)

Comment: I clarified and have still the same problem. I still couldn't find a solution for my problem. You guys would realy help me if you could give it a quick look. Greetings Michael

Answer (score 0):

Add to your script

```py
gmsh.option.setNumber("Mesh.SurfaceFaces", 1)
gmsh.option.setNumber("Mesh.VolumeEdges", 0)
```

You can programmatically change the view in many ways using the settings here:
https://gmsh.info/doc/texinfo/gmsh.html#Gmsh-options